# Problems executing ruby scripts trhough bundle

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, deployment, ssh

I have a ruby on rails project in my server and this users:

projectUser: the user that owns the folders of the project, and when execute

```
bundle exec rails runner script/some-script.rb
```

it works

myUser: I logged with it and is in the sudoers group, so I do this:

```
sudo su 

su projectUser

cd path/toRuby/OnRailsApp

bundle exec rails runner script/some-script.rb
```

it doesn' work:

```
Coul not find 'some-gem' in any of the sources
Run bundle install to install missing gems
```

when I go from root to projectUser with su -

I have another error:

```
block in <class:Application>': undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
```

so it only works with I make ssh directly with projectUser

I checked the ruby environments and there are different:

su: Uses a different ruby version 2.0.0

projectUser: Uses ruby 2.1.6

su - : Uses ruby 2.1.6, and all looks the same

I do not know how to acces with ssh with myUser, then change to projectUser and make that it works, I not use capistrano but I think that the problem is some thing similar pointed here: [blob](http://capistranorb.com/documentation/faq/why-does-something-work-in-my-ssh-session-but-not-in-capistrano/#) and [stackoverflow](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/26676/how-to-check-if-a-shell-is-login-interactive-batch/26782#26782)

Comment: Which version manager do you use? Gems are (as far as I know) normally installed in user space.

Comment: There is no good reason at all to ever run rails with sudo.

Comment: I do not run rails as sudo, I do su projectUser or su - projectUser before executing bundle

Comment: We do not use any ruby version manager

Answer (score 0):

1. tell me the gem name, may be this gem requires some dependencies.
2. solve the nil class error.
3. you can check which user is running the bundle install. actually we set rvm and ruby path $Home variable. if user is different then, it can not access the homme variable of default user like 'ubuntu', may be  this could be the problem :)
4. may be project-user self .basrc file  where ruby & rvm path setting is required.

Comment: Hi the gem is acts_as_paranoid-0.4.3, but I can install it.

Answer (score 0):

When I log with ssh with user project there is the variable:

```
$ export
...
RAILS_ENV="production"
...
```

when I do the otherUser => root => su - antifraude this variable isn't when you check with export, so you have two solutions:

export this variable execute the script like this

```
RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rails runner script/update_folders_names.rb
```

And with this it works